# Doubts with the Java operators

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation

i was looking some code of some GWT classes, and, shamefully, i was unable to understand this part of code:

```
private void toggleHover() {
    // Toggle hovering.
    int newFaceID = getCurrentFace().getFaceID() ^ HOVERING_ATTRIBUTE;

    // Remove disabled.
    newFaceID &= ~DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE;
    setCurrentFace(newFaceID);
  }
```

I do not know very well the java operators, so, my question is:

What exactly happens in:

a) `getCurrentFace().getFaceID() ^ HOVERING_ATTRIBUTE`

b) `newFaceID &= ~DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE;`

The `&` is a bitwise AND and `^` is a bitwise exclusive OR  operator. This is all I knew about this. But, I dont understand the `~DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE` and what happens in the assings of the values.

This piece of code is from GWT `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CustomButton` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `~` is a unary bitwise NOT operator.

Comment: Which tutorial have you used to learn about bitwise operators?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good tutorials on Bitwise operations in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956160/good-tutorials-on-bitwise-operations-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a bit in the ID that is reserved for the hover status. The expression `getCurrentFace().getFaceID() ^ HOVERING_ATTRIBUTE` appears to *toggle* the hovering attribute of the current face. In other words, if the `HOVERING_ATTRIBUTE` bit is one, it is set to zero; if it's zero, it is set to one.

Another bit must be the disabled status. The expression `newFaceID &= ~DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE` *clears* this bit. That is, the `DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE` bit is set to zero.

Comment: Your answer is a little bit more complete and easy to understand, so I accepted it. Other answers are helpfull too. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

The line with the `^` is toggling the bit that `HOVERING_ATTRIBUTE` stands for.  If the bit was 1, it makes it 0; if the bit was 0, it makes it 1.

The line with the `&= ~` is clearing the bit that `DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE` stands for. No matter what the value of the bit was before that, the bit will now be 0.

The `~` thingie alone inverts all the bits of `DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE`, so the result is what we call a bit-mask suitable for ANDing: the bit that `DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE` stands for becomes 0, and all other bits become 1.  So, if you AND any value with this mask, the result is that this bit will be cleared, and all other bits will remain unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

`~` is a bitwise NOT operator in Java.

In total, the operation in b) is that it takes the NOT of `DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE`, ANDs it with `newFaceID`, and assigns it to `newFaceID` (which is a masking operation).

Answer (score 1):

`~` is bitwise `NOT`.

It will reverse each of the bits of `DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE`.

Answer (score 1):

This is good old C-style bitmasking. The FaceID integer number stores a set of bits that represent the selected boolean attributes.

E.g. HOVERING_ATTRIBUTE is 2, DISABLED_ATTRIBUTE is 4.

By running a bitwise xor (^) and a bitwise not (~) it is possible to set or unset these two bits, while keeping other bits intact.